# Valgrind Massif - Track memory allocation in a specific function

Tags: c++, valgrind, profiler

I am using Valrgind-Massif to monitor memory allocation in my program. The default output of Massif contains all allocations throughout the program. However, I would like to only inspect memory allocation in one specific function. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60171507/1130270.